# How do I obtain access to buy from Cisco directly?

Tags: cisco

I'm fairly new to the purchasing and licensing of new Cisco equipment. In the past, I have used eBay for all of my Cisco shopping needs. I know that I can purchase new equipment and licenses from partners/resellers, but how does one become a reseller themselves? Or more to the point: what steps must be taken so that I can purchase directly from Cisco the same way a reseller does? In other words, if I wanted to buy a new specific router, or obtain access to a specific IOS download, etc, is there any way to do this without going through a reseller?

edit: I should clarify that I am aware that Cisco has an application process available on their site, but I have gone through it and found it thoroughly confusing. As someone who is new to this, I was hoping someone could clarify things and shed some light on the subject.

Comment: I didn't think that it falls outside the realm of network engineering because in smaller organizations it is often the network engineer responsible for the purchase of new equipment and software upgrades, and I was trying to find out if there's a way to do it directly instead of going through a partner. I believe I was misunderstood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(while not *network engineering* per-se, it's a good question)

Unless you plan on buying millions in equipment and/or software annually, Cisco will not want to deal with you directly.  This is *especially* true if you're only interested in individual purchases -- that's why they have resellers and channel partners.  If you *are*, then Cisco will assign you a sales person and sales engineer to meet your needs.

Becoming a partner/reseller is an involved process, well beyond the scope of stackexchange. (that's a "*how do I start a business*" question.)